# JSON parse error VOLLEY

Tags: android

```
data: [
{
id: 1,
studentId: "2720303328388783",
first_name: "Edward",
last_name: "Quigley",
middle_name: "Stracke",
extension_name: null,
course: "exploit integrated bandwidth",
address: "428 Donato Glen
Guidoport, NC 81721-6426",
contact_number: "(235) 616-6892 x70184",
email: "bemard@example.com",
batchyear: "1982",
created_at: "2017-09-13 04:07:43",
updated_at: "2017-09-13 04:07:43"
},
{
id: 2,
studentId: "2550068785975308",
first_name: "Maci",
last_name: "Marquardt",
middle_name: "Kuhic",
extension_name: null,
course: "revolutionize collaborative e-tailers",
address: "96424 Buckridge Branch Suite 321
New Yasmine, WV 48806",
contact_number: "1-873-516-0722",
email: "kelli.hoeger@example.net",
batchyear: "1982",
created_at: "2017-09-13 04:07:43",
updated_at: "2017-09-13 04:07:43"
},



    JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET,json_url,(String)null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
//                        Log.d("asdasd","asdasdasd"+response.toString());

//                        JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("data");
//                        try {
//                            Log.e("aaaaaaa", "asdasdasd"+String.valueOf(response.getJSONObject(1)));
//                        } catch (JSONException e) {
//                            e.printStackTrace();
//                        }
                        int count = 0 ;
                        while(count<response.length()){

                            try {
                                JSONObject jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(count);

                                Contact contact = new Contact(jsonObject.getString("id"), jsonObject.getString("studentId"));
                                arrayList.add(contact);
                                count++;
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }


                        }

                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                Toast.makeText(context,"Error....."+error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                error.printStackTrace();
            }

        });
        Mysingleton.getInstance(context).addToRequestque(jsonArrayRequest);

        return arrayList;
    }
```

im having trouble parsing the JSON using VOlley i tried it before with the defaulthttprequest , but with volley im knda bit confused .... help me out please

Comment: show full json and show logcat

Comment: `im having trouble parsing the JSON` don't you mind specifying which problems exactly?

Comment: Can you ellaborate your question properly? Like what error are you getting?